# How to insert data into database with encoded HTML tags using JavaScript and PHP through rich text editor?

Tags: javascript, php, html, escaping, rich-text-editor

I am working on a project where I have to insert data into database using [tinymce](https://www.tiny.cloud/) or [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/). But the problem is, the HTML tags are not getting inserted into database! Here is my codes.

**My HTML**

```html
<form action="action.php" method="POST" id="dataForm">
    <textarea name="details" class="tinymce"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="dataBtn">Add Post</button>
    <div id="dataResult"></div>
</form>
```

**My JavaScript**

```js
$('#dataBtn').click(function(){
    $.post(
    $('#dataForm').attr('action'),
    $('#dataForm').serializeArray(),
        function(result) {
            $('#dataResult').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

**My PHP**

```php
$details = $_POST['details'];

$flag  = false;
$error = [];
$valid = [];

if (!empty($details)) {
    $flag = true;
} else {
    $error[] = "Provide details!";
    $flag    = false;
}

if ($flag == true) {

    $query  = "INSERT INTO tbl_post(details)VALUES('$details')";
    $result = $db->insert($query); // $db is database class

    if ($result) {
        $valid[] = "Data added successfully!";
    } else {
        $error[] = "Something is not right! please try again later!";
    }

} else {
    $error[] = "Something went wrong!";
}
```

Data is getting inserted into database but without the rich text editor formatting or you can say without the HTML tags. I want to know what I have to do with my code to insert data with HTML tags. Thanks.

Comment: To answer this it would be essential really to see the PHP code used to do the inserts/

Comment: please check. thanks.

Comment: Follow [this](https://www.codexworld.com/save-html-editor-content-in-database-php-mysql/) article, You detail column in DB should be something like `details text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`

Comment: @navnath the link you shared, yes that is possible. But, if you use JavaScript to send the input values to your PHP file then the HTML tags are getting removed automatically before it's reaching to your PHP script. I am looking for a solution where I can keep the HTML tags while it's passing JavaScript.

Comment: @Bearded I think `$('#dataForm').serializeArray` will not give value from textarea as html, instead to get content from tinymce do like [var details = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/) then pass in post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/) to get html content from tinymce editor

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    ...
});
  

$('#dataBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // to get html content from tinymce
    var myContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
    const data = $('#dataForm').serializeArray();
    data.push({name: 'details', value: myContent});

    $.post(
        $('#dataForm').attr('action'),
        data,
        function(result) {
            $('#dataResult').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

In PHP

```
$details = json_decode($_POST['details'], true);
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/imnavnathjadhav/pen/JjyWKWV)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working perfectly. but `$details = json_decode($_POST['details'], true);` giving me an empty textarea. So I used `$details = $_POST['details'];` and `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` also `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`